# Play framework or Meteor.js

Tags: meteor, playframework-2.0, typescript

Can anybody tell the pros and cons of developing a webapp using PlayFramework or Meteor.js + TypeScript.
What is better for high scaleable webapp?

Comment: Well, with Play you don't have to use Javascript on backend. It's a killer to me :)

Comment: Its a good point, but still - what about framework possibilities, documentation, support... What about working with frontend on Play?

Comment: This is an apples to oranges comparison. There are far too many differences to account for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scala wins on high scalability.

I played with Scala Play using an old book **Play for Scala: Covers Play 2**. I recently purchased **Discover Meteor**. So I know both technologies.

**Meteor.js**

Pros

- easy to get started
- fast prototyping
- vibrant community. Lot of packages on https://atmospherejs.com/
- easy deployment on meteor.com

Cons

- Node.js is slow heavy computations
- Tied with MongoDB. This is an issue with Meteor. Other Node.js framework support any kind of DB.

**Scala Play 2**

Pros

- runs on top of JVM. All Java libraries are interoperable. JVM is battle tested.

Cons

- smaller community
- compilation time is long.

Note : Both hot reload all code modifications.